# Recover database using only part of binary log MySql

Tags: mysql, recovery, binary-log

I have made a backup, then I have executed several statements, including a delete. So I have recovered the backup but I only want to recover the binary log until before the delete operation, what command can I use for this?

Comment: have you checked the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery-binlog.html

Comment: I found "mysqlbinlog --start-position=155 --stop-position=232 /var/lib/mysql/bin.123456 \ | mysql -u root -p" but i dont understand this: "/var/lib/mysql/bin.123456 \ |"

Comment: what did you don't understand, you find the position where the recovery shpould stop  and set the end pont, that we can't help you with. the rest is linux specific but windows also has piping. so read the steps againcarfully it is all explained, and if you have a specific question maybe dba is a better palce for this. but your question is too briad

Comment: but is it the mysqlbinlog command that performs the recovery? only that?

Comment: yes the binlog command take the selected datadat and transfers it to the database that iot the last part after |

Comment: To be clear: `mysqlbinlog` itself does not apply changes to your database. The _output_ of `mysqlbinlog` is a stream of SQL statements, and you must use that like an SQL script, as the _input_ to `mysql`, the command-line client. You should read the documentation linked to above.